# Can I restore previous contents of the clipboard on Windows?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, clipboard

I had filled in an application form in which I made a payment and copied the application number by "Ctrl+C" command (and unfortunately I didn't note it anywhere).

And after that I copied some other thing but I didn't notice my application number has washed off from the temporary memory. I even tried to login but was unsuccessful.

I now need help: is there any method to print all copied things (I have not copied any file only some text like email id's and else). I have not turned off my PC since that. Please tell is there any method to print on note pad or any other?

Comment: Are you on a PC or a Mac?

Comment: What OS are you using (Windows 10, OSX 10.10, etc) ?

Comment: Wouldn't your application number be emailed to you after you made the payment? Aside: this is off-topic here (you want _Super User_) and I have downvoted for the shouting and begging in the title.

Comment: My tip: please ask about specific concept of programming. This site is provided for questions as "my code isn't working" etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Systems do not save the clipboard history. There is only one item stored in the clipboard. If you copy something new the previous clipboard contents is overwritten and lost forever. To get the full Microsoft clipboard history you need to use third-party utilities such as clipdiary or Clipboard History extension.

Comment: These utilities  tools work after you installed to your machine or added to the browser as extension. for ex- You can download clipdiary from the following link : http://clipdiary.com/clipboard-articles/microsoft-clipboard-history.php or add Clibboard History to your extension option in Google chrome